# Unable to load custom openapi.yaml file using springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springdoc

I am using Spring Boot 3 and the library `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` for swagger documentation. The swagger ui works fine `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html` when it reads from the existing controllers. My current dependencies are as follows -

```
        <!-- Swagger dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.45</version>
        </dependency>
```

But now I am trying to use a custom yaml file which has the openapi specs defined in it. For this I added the following in my `application.properties` file

```
springdoc.api-docs.path=classpath:/swagger-config.yaml
```

On running the server again, the same swagger link gives the following error `Failed to load remote configuration.` [image]

I tried various other configurations, but none seem to pick up the specs from the `swagger-config.yaml` file. Any inputs here would be highly helpful !!!

Please note that my `swagger-config.yaml` is a valid file and it works perfectly fine in the online swagger [editor](https://editor.swagger.io/).

Answer (score 1):

The property you'll want to set is `springdoc.swagger-ui.url` not `springdoc.api-docs.path`.

`springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/swagger-config.yml` should do the trick.

Also, note that the YML file should be put inside `src/main/resources/static` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks.
I have this setup: `springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/api.yml` and then the `api.yml` file under `src/main/resources/static folder`.

Not I had to do a `mvn package` for it to appear there.